# how do I get the width from a label?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

This is my code, and every time I get `null`. Why??

```
$('label[for="name"]').width();
```

This label is created by validation jQuery plugin, so it only has a class error on it. So I need to specifically call this label, and get the width.

And this is my HTML:

```
<div class="input-field">
     <input type="text" name="prenom" id="name" 
            size="30" class="text-input-big error"                 
            placeholder="PRÉNOM">
     <label for="name" class="error">Le prénom est requis</label> 
</div>
```

Comment: Because there's no element matching the selector...? Show us your markup, or an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), or something sufficient to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Try putting an ID on it, and check for that.

Comment: Show us your HTML as well

Comment: @ExplosionPills, there! I just added it

Comment: @Monica we need more details: http://jsfiddle.net/QPVrt/

Comment: @ExplosionPills http://jsfiddle.net/dGXbd/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks correct to me.  Where are you calling this function?
I did it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert($('label[for="name"]').width()); 
});
```

If you run it before the DOM is ready it will return 0

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was solved by doing the following.

```
    $( window ).load(function() {
    $( "#form" ).submit(function( event ) {         
        var rightNameWidth = $('.input-field.name label').width(); 
        console.log(rightNameWidth);
        $('.name label').css('right', '-'+rightNameWidth+'px');
        event.preventDefault();
    });         
});
```

Was cause the DOM was not ready